# Is there a way to specify tsc's --build flag from tsconfig.json?

Tags: typescript, create-react-app, tsconfig, tsc, yarn-workspaces

**tl;dr: What's the tsconfig.json equivalent of `tsc --build`?**

I'm using yarn workspaces - my workspaces are `frontend`, `backend`, and `shared`. I use TypeScript's "project references" to let the frontend and backend code both import from shared.

With project references, [you have to use the `tsc --build` flag](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/project-references.html#caveats-for-project-references). This is fine when I'm building the backend, because I control the `tsc` invocation.

But in the frontend, I'm using create-react-app, which means that I *don't* control the flags passed to `tsc`, but I *do* control the `tsconfig.json`. I can probably use something like craco to hack the tsc flags that react-scripts uses, but if there's a way I can set the flag from the config file that would be much nicer.

I've googled and scoured the typescript docs and haven't found a way to set CLI flags from a config file. Is there one?

Answer (score 0):

I did not find a way to send the `--build` parameter to `tsc` directly from the script that starts the application, but you can execute the compiler in a pre-start script, and send the parameter there, like this:

```
"scripts": {
  "prestart": "tsc --build",
  "start": "nodemon ./src/server.ts"
}
```